# Different Derived Class' Access Modifiers from a Single Base Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, hierarchy, access-modifiers

I would not like to write the same code until it's necessary.

There should be a base class (interface doesn't suit, i suppose)

```
public class MyUser
{
    public string Username
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    //...many other fields
}
```

In one of derived classes, PRIVATE set modifiers (aka Only for this Class' methods) are required.

```
public class MyPrivateInfo : MyUser//, IMyUser
{
    public string Username
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

In the other class, INTERNAL modifiers (aka Library-Wide scope) are required.

```
public class MyLibInfo : MyUser//, IMyUser
{
    public string Username
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }
    //...many other fields
}
```

I suppose there's the way to make a field of type MyUser, that's however not the aim. Fields should be directly accessible in each class.

What's the best way to accomplish this or there is not one?

Comment: In your derived classes you are actually hiding the the base class property and creating a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you *can* use an interface for this. You just need to not specify a `set` method.

This will allow you to define whatever accessibility for a `set` that you want.

```
public interface IUser
{
    string Username { get; }
}

public class MyPrivateInfo : IUser
{
    public string Username
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public class MyLibInfo : IUser
{
    public string Username
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }
}
```

Comment: so I still have to specify every property and there's really no more generic way? The only advantage of this would be that if Interface changes then compiler will prompt about all places where the changes took place (e.g. added new members)?

Comment: @gr9zev - With your requirement of having a customisable access modifies, you are right - you will have to redeclare these properties.